# Separate one array with a hyphen

Tags: java, arrays

I'm stuck on a school project. I'm supposed to print an array with [input] amount of randomized digits between 1-999 that have been sorted. First by odd and even but also ascending / descending. I'll give you guys a quick demonstration of how the program is supposed to work:

- Enter the amount of digits you want to randomize: 10;
- Your numbers are: 5, 818, 916, 935, 464, 89, 275, 470, 209, 388
- Your numbers sorted: 388, 464, 470, 818, 916, 935, 275, 209, 89, 5
- Out of the above 10 numbers, 5 were even and 5 were odd.

I got the sorting right, with the ascending even numbers to the left and the descending odd numbers to the right. But here's the problem I got. I want to separate these 2 categories with a hyphen (and I can't use arrayList). Like following:

- Your numbers sorted: 388, 464, 470, 818, 916 - 935, 275, 209, 89, 5

I can print my full code here for anyone willing to help me think!

````
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("How many random numbers in the range 0 - 999 are desired?");

    int randNum = 0;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    randNum = scan.nextInt();

    int min = 1;
    int max = 1000;
    int evenAmount = 0;
    int oddAmount = 0;
    int[] arr = new int[randNum];
    
      for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max);
      }  

      for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
          evenAmount++;
        }
        else 
        {
          oddAmount++;
        }
      }
  
      Integer[] even = new Integer[evenAmount];
      Integer[] odd = new Integer[oddAmount];
      int a = 0;
      int b = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
          even[a++] = arr[i];
        }
        else
        {
          odd[b++] = arr[i];
        }
      }
    
    Arrays.sort(even);
    Arrays.sort(odd, Collections.reverseOrder());
    
    System.out.println("\n" + "Here are the random numbers: " + "\n");
    
      for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + ", ");
        System.out.print("");
      }
    
    Integer[] result = new Integer[evenAmount + oddAmount];
    
    String[] strEven = new String[evenAmount];
    String[] strOdd = new String[oddAmount];
    String[] strSeparate = {"-"};

      for (int i = 0; i < evenAmount; i++) 
      {
        strEven[i] = String.valueOf(even[i]);
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < oddAmount; i++)
      {
        strOdd[i] = String.valueOf(odd[i]);
      }
  
    
    System.arraycopy(even, 0, result, 0, evenAmount);  
    System.arraycopy(odd, 0, result, evenAmount, oddAmount);

    

    System.out.println("\n" + "\n" + "Here are the random numbers arranged: " + "\n");

      for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(result[i] + ", ");
      }
    
    System.out.println("\n" + "Out of the above " + arr.length + " numbers, " + evenAmount + " were even and " + oddAmount + " were odd.");  
    
    scan.close();
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But here's the problem I got. I want to separate these 2 categories
> with a hyphen (and I can't use arrayList). Like following:
>
> ```
> Your numbers sorted: 388, 464, 470, 818, 916 - 935, 275, 209, 89, 5
> ```

You already know how many even numbers there are with your `evenAmount` variable. You can use that to determine when to print a "-" instead of a ",". You can also not print a "," after the last item with a little more checking:

```
System.out.print("Your numbers sorted: ");
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(result[i]);

    if (i < (result.length - 1)) {
        System.out.print(((i + 1) == evenAmount) ? " - " : ", ");
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: As an exercise for the reader: you can do the same thing with an if statement. This might be more natural than using the ternary operator if you aren't familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative solution in pseudocode. I will leave turning this into actual code as an exercise:

```
Use a for loop to print the even numbers from index 0 to index evenAmount
Print a hyphen
Use a for loop to print the odd numbers from index evenAmount to the end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `arrays.toString()` to convert the array to a string so you can insert the hyphen.

Comment: I thought about that, but how do you insert a hyphen at it's dedicated spot?